# how to solve this issue in postfix

Tags: 16.04, postfix

"i did my setup my postfix by https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-as-a-send-only-smtp-server-on-ubuntu-16-04 but of late am facing this error"

```
  postconf: fatal: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 30: missing '=' after  attribute name: "smtpd relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination"
  postconf: fatal: /etc/postfix/main.cf, line 30: missing '=' after attribute name: "smtpd relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination"
```

main.cf file

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version
# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no
# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no
# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h
readme_directory = no
# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = Exeter-ThinkCentre-E73
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, $mydomain
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
inet_protocols = all
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing an underscore (_) in *line 30* between `smtpd` and `relay`:

```
smtpd_relay_restrictions = [...]
```

Comment: oops a simple one

Comment: i did enter this code  `$ echo "This is the body of the email" | mail -s "This is the subject line" harri.exeter@gmail.com` .but i didnt get ant mail

Comment: @Harri that is a new question. Please mark the answer as correct (as it appears to be the correct answer to your question), then look for the solution to this new issue, and ask another question if you can't find it.

Comment: @zwets yes  mate but again i cant post the whole code and do repetitive stuff

Comment: @Harri this is a new question anyway. You most probably changed your config in the mean time and we will ask you for some additional info which is not at all related to the original typo.